# Wrong Sub-Page Order

Tags: pages

I've got this code to display sub-pages of page with their template,

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    // is Page a parent page
    if ( $post->post_parent == 0 ) {
        // on a parent page, get child pages
        $pages = get_pages( 'hierarchical=1&parent=' . $post->ID );
        // loop through child pages
        foreach ( $pages as $post ){
            setup_postdata( $post );
            // get the template name for the child page
            $template_name = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
            $template_name = ( 'default' == $template_name ) ? 'page.php' : $template_name;
            // default page template_part content-page.php
            $slug = 'page';
            // check if the slug exists for the child page
            if ( locate_template( basename( $template_name ) , $load, $require_once ) != '' ) {
                $slug = pathinfo( $template_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
            }
            // load the content template for the child page
            get_template_part( $slug );
        }
    }
?>
```

But they aren't showing in order that has been signed to them in wordpress control panel. Is there any way to force the hierarchical order?

Comment: you're not setting any `sort_column`, so it defaults to `title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'parent' => $post->ID
); 
$pages = get_pages($args);
```