# Order pages by date

Tags: pages

I'm trying to make a onepager and load all my pages into one page, if that makes sense?

Right now it gets ordered by alfabetical title. I want it to order by date.

This is the website: http://st358373.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/aljen/home/

I've already tried this method and then Wordpress doesn't load the pages: [Wrong Sub-Page Order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217482/wrong-sub-page-order)

```
$pages = get_pages();

foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title   = $page_data->post_title;
    $slug    = $page_data->post_name;

    echo "<div class='$slug'>";
    echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
    echo $content;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Did you check out the documentation for the ordering argument for get_pages or get_posts/WP_Query?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use below filter in your theme file.

```
function orderby_date( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return str_replace( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_date", "CAST({$wpdb->posts}.post_date AS DATE)", $orderby );
}

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'orderby_date', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Worked with this: $args = array(
     'sort_order' => 'asc',
     'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
     'hierarchical' => 1
 );

I had to write it a little bit different.